# Rails: simple routing question about :as => :something

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Using Rails 3.1 (not sure if this is applicable to 3.0, etc.)

In **routes.rb** what's the difference between:

```
  match "team" => "users#index"
```

and

```
  match "team" => "users#index", :as => :team
```

I ask because [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes) say:

---

**3.6 Naming Routes**
You can specify a name for any route using the :as option.

```
 match 'exit' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :logout
```

This will create logout_path and logout_url as named helpers in your application. Calling logout_path will return /exit

---

But, in first example above I have access to team_path & team_url in my views?!? So what's the :as => :team do exactly? I must be overlooking something as I've seen example code written like:

```
match "logout" => "sessions#destroy", :as => :logout
match "login" => "sessions#new", :as => :login
match "signup"  => "users#new", :as => :signup
```

though from my limited testing the `:as => :something` seems redundant?!?

Answer (score 2):

It seems redundant but it's not... when the name of your route differ from the name you want to give.

The ActionDispatcher does a lot of things by default. You should try to trigger `rake routes` in your console to test this behavior.

Another example is the shortcut:

```
match "account/profile"
# same as
match "account/profile", :to => "account#profile"
```

which will create the named route: `account_profile`